# Unable to include local maven dependancy in .jar build

Tags: java, maven

I have the following maven dependancy in my project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.5.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>/Users/alex/code/scratch/src/assets/ojdbc14.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

When building within the IntelliJ IDE it works as expected and I'm able to interact with my Oracle DB as expected.

However when I try to build it in the CLI with:

```
mvn clean compile assembly:single
```

The build will complete but when running my .jar I get the following:

```
Exception occurred: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

I'm not really sure why I'm able to use the dependancy from within IntelliJ but not when it's compiled out.

For reference here is also my assembly plugin config:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>scratch</finalName>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>scratch.Scratch</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

How can I change my set up so that I can package my ojdbc14.jar into the build of my project. Or do I have to always supply the dependant jar along with my jar?

Edit: I have also tried the following

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=src/assets/ojdbc14.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=oracle -Dversion=10.2.0.5.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

with the output:

```
    --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) @ scratch ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/alex/code/scratch/src/assets/ojdbc14.jar to /Users/alex/.m2/repository/com/oracle/oracle/10.2.0.5.0/oracle-10.2.0.5.0.jar
[INFO] Installing /var/folders/0w/3mt249xn54d88n7zptdbjjbh0000gn/T/mvninstall4687156200536752767.pom to /Users/alex/.m2/repository/com/oracle/oracle/10.2.0.5.0/oracle-10.2.0.5.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

Comment: Start to use a repository manager and upload that jar to it. Afterwards you can simply use it as a dependency. System Scope is deprecated and will print WARNING in your build...

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a caching problem in your local repository.

- Delete the directory `/Users/alex/.m2/repository/com/oracle/oracle/10.2.0.5.0/`
- Run your `install:install-file` again.
- Try `mvn clean install`